# Calcular diferencia entre monitores

Tags: c#

estoy desarrollando un programa para poder controlar el ratón de un pc desde otro, lo estaba probando cuando me doy cuenta que el tamaño de mi monitor es mas pequeño que el otro por lo que la flecha esta limitada al tamaño del monitor donde se esta moviendo la flecha, he pensado en hacer un calculo sacando la diferencia de los monitores pero no se como aplicarlo a los ejes X e Y.

Comment: Esta pregunta, déjame decirte, está muy, muy, MUY interesante. +1

Comment: Estoy tratando de encontrar una formula, si encuentro la solución la documentaré

Comment: ¿Sacando la relación de *ppi* de un monitor a otro no puedes sacar la nueva posición (x, y)? Me explico, supongamos que el primer monitor (M1) tiene 10ppi (M1ppi) y el segundo monitor (M2) tiene 5ppi (M2ppi), la relación entre ambos es `M2ppi/M1ppi` *(5/10 = 1/2)*. Por ello, `(x2, y2) = (x1 * M2ppi/M1ppi, y1 * M2ppi/M1ppi)`. Del mismo modo, `(x1, y1) = (x2 * M1ppi/M2ppi, y2 * M1ppi/M2ppi)`. No lo publico como respuesta porque no estoy del todo seguro que funcione, pero es una idea...

Comment: Lo probaré, esa formula era parecida a la yo había pensado

Comment: @VRoxa esta es la formula que he seguido `ejeX = ejeX * (ancho / ancho2)` y `ejeY = ejeY * (alto / alto2)` y funciona perfectamente

Comment: ¡Me alegro! La verdad, estoy más en el mundo del *back-end development* lo cual implica muchos quebraderos de cabeza... Pero al menos me puedo despreocupar de este tipo de problemas como las dimensiones de los dispositivos... Por eso no estaba del todo seguro con la fórmula que te proporcioné; nunca me he encontrado con un problema similar. Me alegra que lo hayas resuelto.

Comment: Si, yo ahora mismo hago un poco de todo y personas que ayudan como tu se agradece mucho.